# What are the Grammar rules in gesucht haben könnte

Tags: standard-german

Yesterday, I watched a episode of Tatort. I didn't understand the structure of following sentence.

> Gibts einen Hinweis, wonach der Täter gesucht haben könnte.

I checked konjunktiv 2 Vergangenheit sentence structure. They have wären / hätten +      Partizip II. Please explain the grammatic structure of the given sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your question is about the verbal structure in

> ...wonach der Täter gesucht haben könnte.

First, lets rewrite this as a *Hauptsatz*:

> Danach könnte der Täter gesucht haben.

From this we see that the predicate is just *könnte*: Konjunktiv II in Präteritum.  The rest, *gesucht haben*, is only an argument of that predicate.  And it is the perfekt infinitive of *suchen*.  Just like the English construction

> The suspect [could] [have searched] for it.

where "to have searched" fulfills the same role.

A minor point, and likely the source of confusion, is that *wonach* starts a relative sentence, which requires the verb-last order.  The Hauptsatz-form with *danach* should make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the last-verb rule with wonach. I was confused with haben gesucht. I thought könnte gesucht haben is predicate in the sentence.  Is it also correct to make it in following way.      Danach hätte der Täter gesucht.

Comment: That would be grammatical, but different: now it's _suchen_ in Konjunktiv II Perfekt. You'd use it for reported speech, or potentiality ("he would have searched").